# Find Diffeomorphism of Torus?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

In this post [Flat tori as a riemannian product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886003/flat-tori-as-a-riemannian-product), it is shown that every flat torus is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda$ for $\Lambda$ a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I have a torus with Riemannian metric

$$g(\theta_1, \theta_2) = \begin{bmatrix} 0.075\cos(\theta_2) + 0.16 & 0.038\cos(\theta_2) + 0.045 \\
0.038\cos(\theta_2) + 0.045 &                      0.045\end{bmatrix}$$

I have shown it has zero sectional curvature everywhere.

My questions are,

1. Is this a flat torus? If so, how would I find that lattice $\Lambda$ from the above-cited post?
2. Is there a diffeomorphism from this torus to the standard torus $\mathbb{R}^2/(\vec{e}_1, \vec{e}_2)$ that carries the Riemannian metric from this torus onto the standard one? If so, in this post [Map Induced on $H_1(T^2)$ by Rotation by Irrational Angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733773/map-induced-on-h-1t2-by-rotation-by-irrational-angle), it is shown that every diffeomorphism of $T^2$, f, is of the form $f=f_0 \circ f_A$ for $f_0 \in \text{Diff}_0(T^2)$ and $f_A$ left-multiplication by $A \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. How would I find $f_0$ and $A$?

EDIT: Maybe there is an $f_0 \in \text{Diff}_0(T^2)$ with $f_0$ being an isometry between $(T^2,g)$ and $\mathbb{R}^2/\Lambda$ for $\Lambda \ne (\vec{e}_1, \vec{e}_2)$? If so, how would I find $f_0$ and $\Lambda$?

Comment: Flat = having zero sectional curvature, so the answer to your first point should tautologically be yes.
As for the second point: all tori are diffeomorphic, regardless of the metric. Maybe you were thinking about finding an isometry?

Comment: 1) Thank you, it is good to know it is flat. 2) Yes, the diffeomorphism should be an isometry carrying the one onto the other.

Comment: To find the lattice, you should look for the two shortest closed geodesics, and the angle they form when they intersect. The two generators of the said lattice will be two vectors in the plane whose norms are the lengths of the said geodesics, forming the same angle than those geodesics. (I'm not saying that it is easy!). *Generically*, this lattice won't be the one you expect in 2), as this would require both shortest geodesics to have same unit length and to intersect orthogonally (but I can't say your metric is generic among flat metrics just like that)

Comment: OK, and, just to be certain, those two tangent vectors (their norms and the angle between them) will form a lattice to which the torus in question will be isometric to the plane mod that lattice? That is to say, there won't be an element of $\text{Diff}_0(T^2)$ standing between those two tori? Tom Farrell (to name-drop) seemed to imply in an email to me that there might be such an element of $\text{Diff}_0(T^2)$.

Comment: In Prof. Farrell's email, he said to consider $\mathbb{R}^2/(\vec{e}_1, \vec{e}_2)$ and any old self-diffeomorphism. If we give the image the push-forward metric, 1) the geodesics in the image likely wouldn't be "straight" circles and 2) their lifts to the universal cover likely wouldn't be straight lines in the plane. If I just use the standard plane with the lattice given by the tangent vectors, I think that would lead to straight lines being the lifts of geodesics. Hence, my objection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an actual answer, but this is too long for a comment.

> Is this a flat torus? If so, how would I find that lattice Λ from the above-cited post?

If you have already shown that all sectional curvatures of your torus $(S^1\times S^1,g)$ vanish (which I haven't checked), then the metric $g$ is flat *by definition*.
From the classification of flat tori, there exist a lattice $\Lambda \subset \Bbb R^2$ and an isometry $f \colon \Bbb R^2/\Lambda \to (S^1\times S^1,g)$.
The metric on the left is the one obtained from the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^2$.

Here is how to construct the corresponding lattice.
Let $\gamma_1$ (resp. $\gamma_2$) be the shortest (resp. second shortest) closed unit speed geodesic in $(S^1\times S^1,g)$.
Let $p_0$ be the point where they intersect.
Up to translating the time parameter, $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, we can assume that $\gamma_1(0) = \gamma_2(0) = p_0$.
Now, up to replacing $\gamma_2(t)$ with $\gamma_2(-t)$, we can assume that $\langle \gamma'_1(0),\gamma'_2(0) \rangle \geqslant 0$.
Let $u = \gamma'(0)$ and $v = \gamma'(0)$.
Let $\Lambda = \Bbb Z u \oplus \Bbb Z v \subset T_{p_0}(S^1\times S^1) = \Bbb R^2$ (this identification is canonical).
The exponential map $\exp_{p_0} \colon \Bbb R^2 \to (S^1\times S^1,g)$ is a local isometry, and descends as an isometry $f \colon \Bbb R^2 / \Lambda \to (S^1\times S^1,g)$.

> Is there a diffeomorphism from this torus to the standard torus $\Bbb R^2/ \Bbb Z^2$ that carries the Riemannian metric from this torus onto the standard one?

This will be possible if and only if $|u|=|v| = 1$, and $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$, *i.e.* if $\{u,v\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_{p_0}(S^1\times S^1)$.
This is because two flat tori $\Bbb R^2 / \Lambda_1$ and $\Bbb R^2 / \Lambda_2$ are isometric if and only if there exists a linear isometry of $\Bbb R^2$ that sends $\Lambda_1$ to $\Lambda_2$.

> Every diffeomorphism of $T^2$ $f$ is of the form $f=f_0\circ f_1$ for $f_0 \in \mathrm{Diff}_0(T^2)$ and $f_A$ is the left-multiplication by $A\in GL_2(\Bbb Z)$.

Yes, this is true for any diffeomorphism from $\Bbb R^2 / \Bbb Z^2$ **to itself** (so that the comment you added in edit does not make sense).

Finally, let me comment that I computed the area of your torus thanks to WolframAlpha, which seems to be close to 2.6.
The usual torus has unit area.
I might have made an error somewhere, but it seems to me that you torus isn't isometric to the standard flat torus.

Comment: I have one more stupid question (and, I can post this as another question): is every point on the manifold the intersection of two globally length-minimizing geodesics? Per this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646410/how-to-actually-find-a-minimizing-path-on-a-manifold, if I could implement a MATLAB script to "flow" a closed path along a steepest descent vector field to a/the geodesic in its homotopy class rel endpoints, would I be able to implement the algorithm at any point in $M = T^2$ or would there be another problem to find $p$ first/simultaneously?

Comment: @JeffreyRolland No geodesic is globally minimizing on a compact manifold. If you meant "shortest", then the answer is yes on flat tori (which are homogeneous), but no in general: there is no reason for a random point to lie on a systole

Comment: Super! I can't thank you enough! If we ever meet IRL at a conference, I definitely owe you a beverage of your choice. Thanks again!

Comment: @JeffreyRolland Deal! Can take a few years for me to cross the Atlantic though, but I won't forget

Comment: LOL! Anytime I'm over there ...